# How do I install a Python module on localhost so that Ansible finds it?

Tags: mysql, python, ansible

I want to use the `community.mysql.mysql_user` module. It requires PyMySQL or MySQLdb. I installed PyYySQL with `pip3 install pymysql` on localhost, but an error message about the missing PyMySQL still appeared. I thought perhaps I should install to a system directory with sudo, but the error still appeared.

The following did not help either, after uninstalling with pip3 again:

- `sudo apt install --yes python3-pymysql`
- `sudo apt install --yes python3-mysqldb`

The installation command from the PyMySQL page on PYPI (python3 -m pip install pymysql) gave this output:

> Requirement already satisfied: PyMySQL in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (0.9.3)

Localhost is WSL2 Ubuntu 20.04.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`PyMySQL` is a requirement on the host that executes the module. The module needs to be installed on the server running the msql server not the computer where `ansible-playbook playbook.yml` is executed.

Comment: Thanks. I misunderstood what that meant.

Comment: Why is this the case though? I thought ansible didn't require anything special installed on the remote hosts which it manages.

Comment: Ansible is agentless. But it some modules do have dependencies. Under the hood Ansible creates a small python script for each task and some have dependencies. That script is copied to the remote host and executed there. The dependencies are always listed in the documentation.